# why mouseover looks working as mouseenter, just for a short time, not continuesly

Tags: jquery, onmouseover

i bound the mouseover event to an element like this :

```
 $( "#cropshiftbundle" ).bind( "mouseover", function() {
         $("#cropimgbtn").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
  });
```

but the action only happens for a short time (as it was for the mouseenter event), not continuesly.

what should i do for it work without interuption ? (please, i dont need a setInterval as an answer)
cheers!

Comment: do you want the animation to happens as long as the mouse is over the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) event

```
$("#cropshiftbundle").bind("mousemove", function () {
    $("#cropimgbtn").fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200).fadeOut(200).fadeIn(200);
});
```